How to install and use the app depends on libappindicator1 in Ubuntu 24.04?
I am trying to install top tracker provided by Toptal. I am getting this error
*sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/toptracker_1.6.2-6524_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for user: 
Selecting previously unselected package toptracker.
(Reading database ... 204997 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../toptracker_1.6.2-6524_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking toptracker (1.6.2-6524) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of toptracker:
 toptracker depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package toptracker (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 toptracker*

when I tryed to install libappindicator1 then getting
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libappindicator1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libappindicator1' has no installation candidate

Can anyone let me know how to fix this ?

You may need to install & compile the source yourself, as the version now available is 3-1 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libappindicator3-1).  The package you're trying to install was packaged for jammy or 22.04 & earlier

This question is similar to: How to create a meta-package that automatically installs other packages?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can create a fake libappindicator1 package that will install libappindicator3-1

You'll have to ensure the APIs line up, changing version number often indicates a change to interfaces; the system could be unreliable or worse if interfaces changed... Also if app used a GTK2 call those were dropped for example. I suggest doing your homework, or asking for an updated package from the supplier.

@ArchismanPanigrahi The duplicate link that you provided does not work for this question because some of the required dependencies are not available in the default Ubuntu 24.04 repositories. As guiverc suggested in the previous comment this can lead to problems in the case of creating a fake libappindicator1 package that will install libappindicator3-1.

@ArchismanPanigrahi In addition to the aforementioned, the OP accepted my answer and posted a comment that my answer worked.

To install the toptracker_1.6.2-6524_amd64.deb file in Ubuntu 24.04 change directories to the directory that contains the toptracker_1.6.2-6524_amd64.deb file that you downloaded, open the terminal and run the following commands.
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libd/libdbusmenu/libdbusmenu-gtk4_16.04.1+18.10.20180917-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./libdbusmenu-gtk4_16.04.1+18.10.20180917-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb ./libappindicator1_12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./toptracker_1.6.2-6524_amd64.deb


Thanks its worked

Download libappindicator1
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 

Download dependency required by libappindicator1
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libd/libdbusmenu/libdbusmenu-gtk4_16.04.1+18.10.20180917-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb

Install both packages
sudo apt install  ./libappindicator1_12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libdbusmenu-gtk4_16.04.1+18.10.20180917-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb 

Install forticlient downloaded from https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads
sudo apt install ./forticlient_vpn_7.4.0.1636_amd64.deb


thank you, this works for Fortclient VPN
